# Pandoc convert specific parts of document

Tags: pandoc, markdown, lua

I have a markdown file of which I want to convert sometimes only specific parts, sometimes the whole document. I know about lua-filters and fenced div which I think is a possible approach, but how can I "select" which part of the document I'm converting.

Let's say this is my document:

```
# This is my title

This is some common parts for both documents.

:::: DOC1

This is a part for Document 1

::::

:::: DOC2

This is a part for Document 2

::::

Some more common parts...
```

How can I tell pandoc/lue-filter if I want to create "Document1" for example? Can I somehow pass a custom argument from the command line that lua-filter can pick up (e.g. `DOC1` or `full`)?

Any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe split the contents to separate files?

From https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html:

> If multiple input files are given, pandoc will concatenate them all
> (with blank lines between them) before parsing. (Use --file-scope to
> parse files individually.)

Comment: Could be an option, but I prefer to keep the source a single markdown file

Answer (score 0):

If you have lua compiler on the machine you can use this filter ==> [tarleb/noexport-subtrees.lua](https://gist.github.com/tarleb/a0f41adfa7b0e5a9be441e945f843299)

add {.noexport} beside all the sections except the one you want

> pandoc --lua-filter=noexport-subtrees.lua youtMD.md